# Is it possible to create striped array (RAID 0) with two parts on two disks (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, raid, software-raid

I have 2 physical disks. Part of one disk is occupied by Windows 7. I have two not allocated parts on these two disks of equal size. Is it possible to create striped array (RAID 0) with two parts on two disks (parts - not the whole disks)? How?
On Virtual machine I modeled this and It's possible:

[image: It's OK on Virtual machine]

But on my machine in office I can't to add both disks in Striped array wizard - probably because OS installed there - I have following:

[image: situation with real machine]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible - I converted disk0 from basic to dynamic and disk0 appeared in striped array wizard (I ran wizard when disk1 was selected and then added disk0):
[D:\ is striped array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ4PO.png)